# How to use EditTextPreference as a masked Password text field?

Tags: android, textview, android-preferences

I have a very simple question:
I have a `EditTextPreference` dialog which I want to use for getting the user's password and I want it to be masked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Here is a short example using xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/key"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:summary="@string/summary"   
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Or you can use `numberPassword` instead of `textPassword`.

Comment: Excellent! i knew it shoult be simple but i didn't expect it to be that simple...

Comment: I need a similar option, but instead of a single edit text i need 3 edit text in my dialog preference. One for old password, new password and confirm password. Can you give me a sample of how to do this. Tha android sample apidemo has only one edit text preference in a dialog. I do not know whow to change this to fit 3 in a same dialog.

Comment: You should create custom `Preference` that extends `DialogPreference` with custom Dialog.

Comment: but when orientation changes to landscape edittext is displayed on full screen and password is not shown as hidden :(

Comment: But how is it possible to store password or password hash securely? The code `android:key="@string/key"` stores it as plain text.

Answer (score 6):

For `androidx` library you should do it programmatically for example you could do it as follows, optionally I am setting the summary with asterisks according to the length of password:

```
[...]
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

import static androidx.preference.EditTextPreference.*;

public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

        final EditTextPreference preference = findPreference("password");

        if (preference != null) {
            preference.setSummaryProvider(new SummaryProvider() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence provideSummary(Preference preference) {

                    String getPassword = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString("password", "not set");

                    //we assume getPassword is not null
                    assert getPassword != null;

                    //return "not set" else return password with asterisks
                    if (getPassword.equals("not set")) {
                        return getPassword;
                    } else {
                        return (setAsterisks(getPassword.length()));
                    }
                }
            });

            //set input type as password and set summary with asterisks the new password
            preference.setOnBindEditTextListener(
                    new OnBindEditTextListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBindEditText(@NonNull final EditText editText) {
                            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                            preference.setSummaryProvider(new SummaryProvider() {
                                @Override
                                public CharSequence provideSummary(Preference preference) {
                                    return setAsterisks(editText.getText().toString().length());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    //return the password in asterisks
    private String setAsterisks(int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int s = 0; s < length; s++) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

In xml you should have something like:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:dialogMessage="Enter your password"
    android:dialogTitle="Password"
    android:key="password"
    android:title="Password" />
```

For more info please look at [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#customize_an_edittextpreference_dialog)

Comment: How do I get the text when clicking "ok"?

Comment: Works nice. I've created gist with common code separated to external file:
https://gist.github.com/mjfryc/3cb8518e19794dd9ba894eef3daca1d6

Answer (score 4):

`android:inputType="numberPassword"` doesn't work for me. Eclipse told me, that no String values are allowed for this attribute.
So i used following:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/key"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:summary="@string/summary"   
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true" />
```

This got me a EditTextPreference with a dotted textdisplay and a number keyboard for input.

Answer (score 2):

For `AndroidX Preferences`, do:

```
password.setOnBindEditTextListener(editText -> {
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
});
```

The `inputType` XML attribute isn't used on `androidx`.

Comment: This will change only the preference "dialog" to edit  the value. The preference summary will remain visibile with the value in plain text. To customize the preference summary have a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#use_a_custom_summaryprovider

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the code below. HOWEVER, I still haven't figured out how to do the PASSWORD_TOGGLE thing. Doesn't work by just defining **app:endIconMode="password_toggle"** Can someone help with that?

The ANSWER: The "EditTextPreference" field "db_pwd" has the following defined:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

The latest Kotlin rev code:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(com.unified.helloworld.R.xml.my_preferences, rootKey)
    val pwdPref =
        findPreference<EditTextPreference>("db_pwd")
    if (pwdPref != null) {
        pwdPref.summaryProvider = SummaryProvider<Preference?> {
            val getPassword: String =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    .getString("db_pwd", "Not set")!!

            // Return "Not set" else return password with asterisks
            if (getPassword == "Not set") {
                getPassword } else { setAsterisks(getPassword.length) }
        }

        // Set type as password and set summary with asterisks
        pwdPref.setOnBindEditTextListener(
            OnBindEditTextListener { editText ->
                editText.inputType =
                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                pwdPref.summaryProvider = SummaryProvider<Preference> { setAsterisks(editText.text.toString().length) }
            })
    }
}

// Return the password in asterisks
private fun setAsterisks(length: Int): String {
    val sb = java.lang.StringBuilder()
    for (s in 0 until length) {
        sb.append("*") }
    return sb.toString() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the password mask persist also after device rotation is suffice to add the following `imeOption`:

in the edit text layout

`android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

or programmatically

 `yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);`

Comment: And how is it possible to access the edit text layout from `EditTextPreference`?

Comment: Take a look at the EditTextPreference documentation: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#getEditText())

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setImeOptions' in 'EditTextPreference'!