# EditTextPreference does not mask password even with android:inputType="textPassword"

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack

I have following code

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="pref_password"
            app:title="Password"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
            app:dialogTitle="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

But the edit text field is not masked with dots even with `android:inputType="textPassword"`

I am using androidx. Anyone please help

**Update**

I tried following as a commenter suggested, but no luck

```
<EditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_password"
            android:title="Password"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
            android:dialogTitle="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Comment: instead of " app: ", go with " android: ". Link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164430/how-to-use-edittextpreference-as-a-masked-password-text-field

Comment: @VirajS tried, but no luck. updated the question

Comment: Sorry about the constant rollbacking! There was a weird problem with the rollback button. (I intended to roll back the question to before the [tag:kotlin] tag was added as this tag is not relevant to the question)

Comment: @Edric actually I was using kotlin

Comment: Just because you’re using Kotlin doesn’t mean you can add the [tag:kotlin] tag. Tags should only be added if they are a topic in the question itself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting attributes directly on the EditTextPreference doesn't work with the AndroidX library - since an EditTextPreference isnt' an EditText, and shouldn't work as such. Instead you should use an `OnBindEditTextListener` to customize the EditText when it is displayed. (need androidx.preference:preference v1.1.0 and higher)

See the [settings guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#customize_an_edittextpreference_dialog) for more information

edit with code:

**Java:**

```
EditTextPreference preference = findPreference("pref_password");

if (preference!= null) {
    preference.setOnBindEditTextListener(
            new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
            });
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
val editTextPreference: EditTextPreference? = findPreference("pref_password")

        editTextPreference?.setOnBindEditTextListener {editText ->  
            editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
        }
```

Comment: can you add code snippet used to mask text also so answer looks more complete